# Erlang File I/O: Large binary files and gzip streaming

Tags: file, file-io, erlang, gzip

I have two questions regarding Erlang file i/o; what is the best way to achieve in Erlang:

1. reading large binary files (many gigabytes) without copying the whole file into memory
2. reading a gzipped binary file as a decompressed stream

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. See [`file:read/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#read-2) for sequential block access and [`file:pread/2,3`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#pread-2) for random access.
2. See `compressed` option in [`file:open/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#open-2).

Comment: I might have to figure out something that's higher performance for production, but this works very well for prototyping.

Comment: Do you have measured or just guessing? I'm pretty satisfied with  `file:read/2` when opened file using `[raw, binary, read_ahead]` and using block oriented processing. What performance you expect?

Answer (score 5):

According to my experience, *file:read/2* alone will be **very** slow if called frequently with small amounts of data, despite of `read_ahead` and `raw`. You must implement a binary buffer on top of that. If that is meant by block oriented processing then I agree.

I'm talking about runtimes of few hours (with *file:read/2* only) vs. 2 minutes (with buffering implemented in pure Erlang).

Here are my measurements for reading a few 10 bytes at once:

```
%% Bufsize vs. runtime [ns]
%% 50       169369703
%% 100      118288832
%% 1000      70187233
%% 10000     64615506
%% 100000    65087411
%% 1000000   64747497
```

In this example, the performance doesn't really increase over 10 KB buffer size, because the relative overhead for *file:read* becomes small enough.